# How to integrate AWS + ELB + AutoScale + Docker + Spring Cloud

Tags: docker, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-cloud

I want to design an application using AWS as IAAS, Docker as PAAS and Spring Boot and Spring cloud as application technology.

For this, I googled and read a lot of blogs and watch videos but could not find any answer for that.

I developed one application using Spring Boot and Spring cloud technology, and the application architecture looks like below image.

[image]

This design looks good and working fine as per expectation. 
Now the new task is, I need to use the cloud (AWS) as Infrastructure and Docker.
For that, I designed one more architecture, and it looks like below image.

[image]

The component as follows:

ELB - (Elastic Load Balancer) -> Target Group (Part of Auto Scaling) -> EC2 instance (will be created more on demand)

Now if I want to integrate my previous design then I think there is not need of Zuul server here because this load balancing is done by ELB, the second I do not need Service Discovery component as well because it will be done by Target AutoScale group.

I am a little bit confused here with Spring Cloud and AWS infrastructure.

Could someone help me to make really simple how I can integrate these components to work together?

Thanks

Comment: Did you managed to integrate Spring cloud gateway with your ELB ? I am trying to build same solution where ELB will be target uri inside spring cloud gateway not sure if that would work !!

Answer (score 2):

### Why Spring Cloud with AWS ?

Let's take example when you need Spring Cloud even if your architecture is deployed on AWS infra :

Imagine your Product service need to communicate with your Order Service, in this case you will see Spring Cloud utility.

You don't see the necessity of Spring Cloud because you don't have an internal communication (between your services) and this is the role of Registry service.

### Why Gateway service (Zuul in your architecture) ?

Again, your current architecture don't use (need) the powerful of Gateway pattern.

Let's assume your system need to aggregate multiple results from different services to response to client request. You can do this in Gateway (Zuul in your case).

Another advantage to use Gateway service is you can use it as a unified front door to your system, which allows a browser, mobile app or other user interface to consume services from multiple hosts without managing cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) and authentication for each one.

### Important :

It's fine to not use Spring Cloud, is not a rule or THE right way to implement microservices architecture. If you don't need it don't use it.

Comment: Hi RedOff, Thanks for answer. In my current architecture service are communicating to each other. ProductSerice communicates with OrderService, I did not show it diagram.  Second thing about zuul (Gateway Pattern) , I asked, I want to use zuul but bit confuse where to add it because AWS EBS is playing as frontend Gateway. Could you please guide me if I want to use the Zuul with AWS then what should be the right approach.

Comment: I thing you meant _... add it because AWS **ELB** is playing as frontend Gateway_.

You can add Zuul between your ELB and your business services, and maybe remove your target groups (TG), Zuul will forward requests based on instances IDs (if you use Registry service). The only TG that you will have is the Gateway TG (from ELB to Zuul)